# PHP TWITTER bot to follow/unfollow using api version 1.1 and cursors

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

This code should only unfollow users who are not following back, but it unfollows SOME followers, cannot figure out why.

```
$oTwitter = new TwitterOAuth (...)

$aFollowing = $oTwitter->get('friends/ids');
$aFollowing = $aFollowing->ids;
$aFollowers = $oTwitter->get('followers/ids');
$aFollowers = $aFollowers->ids;

$i=1;
foreach( $aFollowing as $iFollowing )
{
$isFollowing = in_array( $iFollowing, $aFollowers );

echo "$iFollowing: ".( $isFollowing ? 'OK' : '!!!' )."<br/>";

if( !$isFollowing )
{
$parameters = array( 'user_id' => $iFollowing );
$status = $oTwitter->post('friendships/destroy', $parameters);
} if ($i++ === 100 ) break;
}
```

Could it be that the problem is something else?

EDIT:
 Added own answer to this post with code that works to follow followers and unfollow non-followers on twitter.

Comment: Are you following / do you have more than 5000 followers? Those API calls have a 5000 id cap, you need to use pagination beyond that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your of followers is greater than 5000 then `$aFollowers = $oTwitter->get('followers/ids');` will only return the first 5000 ids. In what order? Twitter does not guarantee any order, so we'll just assume random.

If the following check `$isFollowing = in_array( $iFollowing, $aFollowers );`, the person `$iFollowing` may or may not be in the list `$aFollowers` depending on how Twitter returned the followers to you. If the person is in the first 5000, then this will work, if they're outside the first 5000 then the check will fail, even if the person is legitimately following you.

You'll need to pull all your followers via cursors. Check out the doc on [cursors / pages](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/misc/cursoring) - will help you out a bit. Basically you need to do this.

```
$aFollowers = array();
$cursor = -1;
do {
  $follows = $oTwitter->get('followers/ids?cursor=' . $cursor);
  $aFollowers = array_merge($follows->ids, $aFollowers);
  $cursor = $follows->next_cursor;
} while ($cursor > 0);
```

Answer (score 7):

This works, I think maybe it can help novices like me. Andy Jones answer really helped. Used great library for many other things as well [here](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/tree/master/src).

```
  require_once 'twitteroauth.php';

 $oTwitter = new TwitterOAuth 
(   'YOUR_TWITTER_APP_CONSUMER_KEY',
'YOUR_TWITTER_APP_CONSUMER_SECRET',
'YOUR_TWITTER_APP_OAUTH_TOKEN',
'YOUR_TWITTER_APP_OAUTH_SECRET');
```

> //FULL FOLLOWERS ARRAY WITH CURSOR ( FOLLOWERS > 5000)

```
$e = 1;
$cursor = -1;
$full_followers = array();
do {

$follows = $oTwitter->get("followers/ids.json?screen_name=yourusername&cursor=".$cursor);

$foll_array = (array)$follows;

  foreach ($foll_array['ids'] as $key => $val) {

        $full_followers[$e] = $val;
        $e++; 
  }
       $cursor = $follows->next_cursor;

  } while ($cursor > 0);
echo "Number of following:" .$e. "<br /><br />";
```

> //FULL FRIEND ARRAY WITH CURSOR (FOLLOWING > 5000)

```
$e = 1;
$cursor = -1;
$full_friends = array();
do {

  $follow = $oTwitter->get("friends/ids.json?screen_name=yourusername&cursor=".$cursor);
  $foll_array = (array)$follow;

  foreach ($foll_array['ids'] as $key => $val) {

        $full_friends[$e] = $val;
        $e++;
  }
      $cursor = $follow->next_cursor;

} while ($cursor > 0);
```

> //IF I AM FOLLOWING USER AND HE IS NOT FOLLOWING ME BACK, I UNFOLLOW
> HIM

```
    $index = 1;
    $unfollow_total=0;
    foreach( $full_friends as $iFollow )
    {
    $isFollowing = in_array( $iFollow, $full_followers );
     
    echo "$iFollow: ".( $isFollowing ? 'OK' : '!!!' )."<br/>";
    $index++;
     if( !$isFollowing )
        {
        $parameters = array( 'user_id' => $iFollow );
        $status = $oTwitter->post('friendships/destroy', $parameters);
        $unfollow_total++;
        } if ($unfollow_total === 5) break;
    }
```

> //IF USER IS FOLLOWING ME AND I AM NOT, I FOLLOW

```
$index = 1;
$follow_total = 0;

foreach( $full_followers as $heFollows )
{
$amFollowing = in_array( $heFollows, $full_friends );
 
echo "$heFollows: ".( $amFollowing ? 'OK' : '!!!' )."<br/>";
 $index++;
 if( !$amFollowing )
    {
    $parameters = array( 'user_id' => $heFollows );
    $status = $oTwitter->post('friendships/create', $parameters);
    $follow_total++;
    } if ($follow_total === 5) break;
}

echo 'Unfollowed:'.$unfollow_total.'<br />';
echo 'Followed:'.$follow_total.'<br />';
```

Comment: The limit is 999? Twitter like that? Should not be something like 10 or 20 to be conservative?

Comment: Yes, this answer was when twitter was in the good old days the wild west and we could do this with no censorship. now a days be very careful... also if your account is new with few followers, be extra careful as twitter might ban your account immediately. Tip, in my experience automated unfollowing is not banned as heavily as automated following

Comment: I will edit the answer in case someone copy pastes as is... keep in mind this is a 2013 script, when you got banned when folowing more than  999 users in bulk. Today this script will work, but you will loose your account the next day at most i guess.

Comment: Yep here are the new limits https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-limits and pay attention to the aggressive term.