# twitter follow/unfolow using PHP?

Tags: php, twitter

I'm trying to create a simple follow and unfollow twitter bot using PHP.

I have found a couple of codes spinets that I thought could get me started.

the codes can be fond here:

[PHP TWITTER bot to follow/unfollow using api version 1.1 and cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799023/php-twitter-bot-to-follow-unfollow-using-api-version-1-1-and-cursors)

I tried to use this code:

```
<?php
 require("twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php"); 

 $oTwitter = new TwitterOAuth 
(   'YOUR_TWITTER_APP_CONSUMER_KEY',
'YOUR_TWITTER_APP_CONSUMER_SECRET',
'YOUR_TWITTER_APP_OAUTH_TOKEN',
'YOUR_TWITTER_APP_OAUTH_SECRET');


$e = 1;
$cursor = -1;
$full_followers = array();
do {

$follows = $oTwitter->get("followers/ids.json?screen_name=myusername&cursor=".$cursor);

$foll_array = (array)$follows;

  foreach ($foll_array['ids'] as $key => $val) {

        $full_followers[$e] = $val;
        $e++; 
  }
       $cursor = $follows->next_cursor;

  } while ($cursor > 0);
echo "Number of following:" .$e. "<br /><br />";
 ?>
```

however, the code above returns this:

```
Number of following:1
```

but I have over 800 following and over 1000 followers!

so the figure being displayed in php wrong!

could someone please advise on this issue?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the result in json format, you have to use `json_decode`, otherwise your `$foll_array` will contain only one string (i.e. the json string). It should be something like this:

```
$e = 1;
$cursor = -1;
$full_followers = array();

do {
$follows = $oTwitter->get("followers/ids.json?screen_name=myusername&cursor=".$cursor);
$foll_array = json_decode($follows);

foreach($foll_array as $key => $val) {
    if($key == 'ids')
    {
        foreach($val as $id)
        {
             $full_followers[$e] = $id;
             $e++; 
        }
    }
}
   $cursor = $foll_array->next_cursor;

} while ($cursor > 0);
```

Comment: I still get the same thing. 1 following.

Comment: I hope you replaced 'YOUR_TWITTER_APP_CONSUMER_KEY',
'YOUR_TWITTER_APP_CONSUMER_SECRET',
'YOUR_TWITTER_APP_OAUTH_TOKEN',
'YOUR_TWITTER_APP_OAUTH_SECRET' with your own login credentials.

Comment: ok, sorry for asking. but it seems to be something wrong with your connection. do you get any errors while executing the script?

Comment: no, nothing, I've given up on it now. spent 4 hours on it and there seems to be an issue with twitter api. I even tried some already made scripts that I found on google and they don't even work. so my conclusion is that there is something wrong with twitter api.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see if you are getting a twitter error. This would mean you are connecting at least.

```
if (isset($follows->errors)) {
    print_r($follows->errors[0]->message);
} else {
    print_r($follows);
}
exit;
```

If not something is wrong with connection data